# ComboBox not calling MyClass.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public BindingList<Class> List = new BindingList<Class>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List.Add(new Class());
        comboBox1.DataSource = List;
    }
}

public class Class : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Class";
    }
}
```

The problem is that the combo box shows the text "(Collection)" instead of "Class". Whenever I remove the `Dictionary<string, string>` as an ancestor of `Class`, the code show's "Class" as I want it to. Even when I derive it from another base class I wrote myself it works OK. This is of course not the real program but the problem isolated. So am I missing something or I don't have a choice other than declare a `Dictionary<string, string>` field in `Class` instead of subclassing it? (Oh, and by the way, I already tried adding a breakpoint in the `ToString` function and it's not being called.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = false;
```

I have tried it and now the combobox shows the text 'Class' and not "(Collection)".

Comment: The .NET databinding implementation is automatically formatting your collection class for you if the Control.FormattingEnabled flag is true. If you want an extended explanation, check out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480734.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could declare your own `BindingList` subclass which also overrides `ToString()` and returns the value of `ToString()` of one of its elements:

```
public class MyBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this.Count == 0)
        {
            return "Empty BindingList";
        }

        return "BindingList of " + this[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Then just use `MyBindingList` where you use `BindingList` in your code.